# AJAX data variable not posting to PHP script, yet $_POST is set

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

This is driving me crazy. I'm trying to post a variable to a PHP script using AJAX but while I can verify that $_POST is set, the varibale remains undefined.

I've used almost identical code elsewhere and it works fine - I just cant see what the problem is here.

Here is a very stripped down version of the code -

**The JS**

```
$(function(){
  $('#load_more_comments').click(function(){

    var newLimit = 40;
      $.ajax({
          url: "scripts/load_comments.php",
          data: { limit: newLimit },
          type: "post",
          success: function(result){

            // execute script

          },
          error: function(data, status, errorString)
        { 
            alert('error');
        }
      });
      return false;
  });
});
```

**The PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST)) {

    echo "POST is set";

    if (isset($_POST['limit'])) {

        $newLimit = $_POST['limit'];
        echo $newLimit;

     }

}
```

**UPDATE**
var_dump($_POST) returns array(0) { } so I know that AJAX is definitely is not posting any values

Comment: And why do you think that variable (what variable exactly) is undefined?

Comment: the variable newLimit that I'm trying to post. I think it's undefined because it if I echo it out php tells me that the variable is undefined...

Comment: Your code seems correct. what the issue you got

Answer (score 0):

Using  slightly modified version of the above I am unable to reproduce your error - it appears to work fine.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        ob_clean();
        if( isset( $_POST['limit'] ) ){
            echo $_POST['limit'];
        }
        exit();
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>

        <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
              $('#load_more_comments').click(function(){

                var newLimit = 40;

                  $.ajax({
                      url: location.href,               //"scripts/load_comments.php",
                      data: { limit: newLimit },
                      type: "post",
                      success: function(result){
                        alert( result )
                      },
                      error: function(data, status, errorString){ 
                        alert('error');
                    }
                  });
                  return false;
              });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- content -->
        <div id='load_more_comments'>Load more...</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
if (count($_POST)) {
```

Instead of

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
```